# phonegap In app browser not closing on back key press

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the cordova 3.3 to open in app browser page,the page opens but the back button is not working on pressing it,the app is frozen in the in app browser page,

```
window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

also the location is not shown in the bottom of the page works fine with the ios (location).

android-4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this for debugging:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the back key event on your application:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
    // Close your window here
},false);
```